# Proof of cuts measurable

Tags: measure-theory

Prove that the set $ D=\{(x,x): x \in [0,\frac{1}{2}]\} $ has all cuts measurable but not measurable against $\sigma $-product body $\mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{A} $.

I started with that: $ D_{x_0}= \{x_0\}$ for $x_0\le \frac{1}{2} $ and $\emptyset $ for $x_{0} > \frac{1}{2}. $

Hence, the set D has all the cuts that are measurable because $\emptyset \in \mathcal{A} $ and $\{x_{0}\} \in \mathcal{A} $. However, I have a problem with proving that $D$ is not measurable in regard of $\sigma $-product body $\mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{A} $. Does anyone have any idea how to prove this?

Comment: Which $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A} $ is being considered?

Comment: We consider space $([0,1],\mathcal{A}) $ where $\mathcal{A}$ is the $\sigma$ field generated by countable subsets of $X$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2401454/does-measurablity-of-cuts-imply-measurability-in-product-space?rq=1

Comment: @wvnikax , I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please, upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, The measurable space is $([0,1],\mathcal{A})$ where $\mathcal{A}$ is the $\sigma$-field generated by the countable subsets of $[0,1]$.

Consider $f: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1] \times [0,1]$  defined by $f(x)=(x,x)$. It is easy to see that $f$ is a measurable function (it is enough to consider the pre-image of rectangles $A \times B$ where $A$ and $B$ are countable or have countable complement).

Now, if $D \in \mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{A} $ then we should have
$ \left [0,\frac{1}{2} \right ] = f^{-1}(D) \in \mathcal{A}$.
So $D \notin \mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{A} $.

**Remark**: Since $\mathcal{A}$ is the $\sigma$-field generated by the countable subsets of $[0,1]$, we have that $\mathcal {A} = \{ E \subset [0,1] : E \textrm{ or } E^c \textrm { is countable }\}$

In fact, it is easy to check that  $\{ E \subset [0,1] : E \textrm{ or } E^c \textrm { is countable }\}$ is a $\sigma$-field and it is clealy the smallest $\sigma$-field containing the countable subsets of $[0,1]$. So $\{ E \subset [0,1] : E \textrm{ or } E^c \textrm { is countable }\}$ is the  $\sigma$-field generated by the countable subsets of $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped me a lot. However, I have a problem understanding the last line: why set $[0,\frac{1}{2}] $ doesn't belong to $\mathcal{A} $?

Comment: @wvnikax , I have added a **Remark** to my answer, including the details. Please, check it.

Comment: I think I understand, in short $D$ is not measurable in regard of $\sigma$ -product field because the set $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ is not countable, right?

Comment: @wvnikax , because $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ is not countable and also its complement is not countable. So $[0,\frac{1}{2}] \notin \mathcal{A}$.